# Safety of casting arbitrary types to usize

Tags: casting, rust, atomic, undefined-behavior

I wrote some code. It works... but is it safe?

```
use std::mem;
use std::ptr;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Atomic<T: Copy>(AtomicUsize, PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: Copy> Atomic<T> {
    unsafe fn encode(src: T) -> usize {
        assert!(mem::size_of::<T>() <= mem::size_of::<usize>());

        let mut dst = 0;
        ptr::write(&mut dst as *mut usize as *mut T, src);
        dst
    }

    unsafe fn decode(src: usize) -> T {
        assert!(mem::size_of::<T>() <= mem::size_of::<usize>());
        ptr::read(&src as *const usize as *const T)
    }

    fn new(val: T) -> Atomic<T> {
        unsafe {
            Atomic(AtomicUsize::new(Self::encode(val)), PhantomData)
        }
    }

    fn load(&self, order: Ordering) -> T {
        unsafe { Self::decode(self.0.load(order)) }
    }

    fn store(&self, val: T, order: Ordering) {
        unsafe { self.0.store(Self::encode(val), order) }
    }
}

impl<T: Copy + Default> Default for Atomic<T> {
    fn default() -> Atomic<T> {
        Self::new(T::default())
    }
}
```

As you can see, I write an arbitrary `Copy` value of small enough size into a `usize`, and ship it around in an `Atomic`. I then read it out as a new value.

In essence I use the `usize` as a memory block of size `size_of::<usize>()`.

If this is safe, the next step is to consider fancier operations.

```
unsafe trait PackedInt {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for u8  {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for i8  {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for u32 {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for i32 {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for u64 {}
unsafe impl PackedInt for i64 {}

impl<T: Copy + PackedInt> Atomic<T> {
    fn compare_and_swap(&self, current: T, new: T, order: Ordering) -> T {
        unsafe {
            Self::decode(self.0.compare_and_swap(
                Self::encode(current),
                Self::encode(new),
                order
            ))
        }
    }

    fn fetch_add(&self, val: T, order: Ordering) -> T {
        unsafe {
            Self::decode(self.0.fetch_add(Self::encode(val), order))
        }
    }

    fn fetch_sub(&self, val: T, order: Ordering) -> T {
        unsafe {
            Self::decode(self.0.fetch_sub(Self::encode(val), order))
        }
    }
}
```

These are of course not always particularly sensible on overflow (since two "equal" values could compare unequal due to bits outside of the `T`), but they still seem well-defined... I think.

So, is this safe, and why?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Rust definition of safety](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-not-considered-unsafe) (also relevant, the [undefined behavior](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-considered-undefined))? Or do you mean a more general type of "safe"?

Comment: The Rust definition, mostly. Comments on especially surprising but-technically-safe problems would be a nice addition, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost safe... but not quite.  You're probably only thinking about people using `Atomic` with integers and floats, but references are also `Copy`.  A user could easily cause a crash using relaxed loads and stores on an `Atomic<&&u32>`.

On a side-note, your `fetch_add` and `fetch_sub` won't work correctly on big-endian systems.

Comment: *on big-endian systems* — it'd be cool if there was a way to have the CI ecosystems (like TravisCI) have ways to test {x86, ARM, ...}, and {big, little}-endian systems in addition to the {32, 64}-bit support I am familiar with.

Comment: Good catch! Using `struct Atomic<'a, T: Copy + 'a>(AtomicUsize, PhantomData<(&'a mut T, T)>);`seems to fix the first issue. :)